# How to filter assisted conversions by goals using Analytics API?

Tags: google-analytics, python-requests, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-filters

I make api call to https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/mcf
with next metric and dimensions:

```
metrics = ['mcf:assistedConversions']
dimensions = ['mcf:adwordsAdContent','mcf:adwordsCampaignID','mcf:adwordsAdGroupID','mcf:adwordsCreativeID', 'mcf:sourceMedium']
```

And as expected API returns SUM of all conversions(all goals and transactions)
In docs I can not find how to filter metric by specific goal.
How I can do that with API? Can I even do that? In web-interface of analytics I can.

Comment: I know it is a long shot, but I couldn't get a reference for any code like this, could you direct me to any documentation o how to make this request?

Answer (score 0):

As I discovered there is a parameter: [mcf:conversionGoalNumber](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/dimsmets/conversionpaths#mcf:conversionGoalNumber)
To filter assisted conversion you need to add param 'filters' like

```
&filters=mcf:conversionGoalNumber==XXX(goal number like 001, 015)
```